# Setting background color of RelativeLayout in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add a background color to the search form area of a RelativeLayout in my Android app in Xamarin. Basically I have an EditText and a button that should be contained within a colored background at the top of the screen. Using the code below, the background color is applied but my EditText and button disappear while the content below them move up and take their place. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:background="#ffffff">

  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/TestLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#EAF4F9">

    <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Heading"
    pixlui:typeface="Lato-Bold.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <EditText
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:id="@+id/SearchField"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <Button
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/SearchField"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
    android:text="Use my current location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/SearchField"
    android:id="@+id/txtCurrentLocation"
    android:gravity="center"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

  <View
  android:id="@+id/strut"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button
  android:id="@+id/btnOne"
  android:text="Button One"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/txtCurrentLocation"
  pixlui:typeface="Lato-Light.ttf"
  android:gravity="center" />

  <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button
  android:text="Button Two"
  android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/txtCurrentLocation"
  android:gravity="center"
  pixlui:typeface="Lato-Light.ttf" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Should I be utilizing a LinearLayout here instead or is there a better way to construct this?

Comment: Why are both elements in the nested `RelativeLayout` using `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"`? Post the entire layout please. With `RelativeLayout` nesting is almost always not needed entirely, which is so cool about it!

Comment: I've edited the above code to show the full layout. Basically you have a heading at the top with a search field below it on the left and a search button to the right of that. Below the search field and button is a button for using current location. All of this should be on a light blue background that spans the width of the parent. How else could I go about achieving this if it doesn't need to be wrapped in some sort of container? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pixlui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.neopixl.pixlui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <View
        android:background="#EAF4F9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnOne" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Hello" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Search for..." />
    <Button
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Use my current location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtCurrentLocation"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:text="Button One"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtCurrentLocation"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just replace the buttons and textviews with the pixlui versions where needed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Didn't realize it was as easy as using a view and defining layout alignment.

Comment: Stuff like this is even better in Android L. So much power in AXML :)